# AJAX open error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, get

getting this error, not sure why... thanks :)

> uncaught **InvalidStateError**: Failed to execute 'send' on '**XMLHttpRequest**': The object's state must be OPENED.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState === 4) {
                            console.log("4 request");
            if(request.status === 200) {
                $(".container").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                console.log("200 request");
            }
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', 'bio.txt', true);

    $("#send-btn").on("click", function(){
        request.send();
    });
});
```

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, why are you not using the jQuery AJAX utilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest objects go through a number of [different states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState).

After you call `request.open` it goes into the OPENED state.

When you click the button it goes through the later states and ends up as DONE.

When you click the button **again** it is DONE and not OPENED so you get the error.

---

Create the XHR object (and call open etc on it) **inside** the `click` event handler.

Comment: Haha thanks again Quentin :)

That resolves the error issue. However for some reason my container isn't adding the text. is 'request.responseText' correct? How does 'responseText' work exactly?

Comment: @JoeConsterdine — `innerHTML` is a property of DOM elements, not of jQuery objects.